# Sqlalchemy how to clear all filters from query

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

Problem.

I have query let say like that:

```
qr = Session.query(models.User).filter(models.User.email == email)
```

What I want to do is to create qr2 with all filters dropped, in my case it would equivalent to:

```
qr2 = Session.query(models.User)
```

Good solution might be either, new query based on old one but without filters or modification of old query.

Why someone might need that.

Imagine you have a complex query that was build 3 modules and 4k lines away. What you get in your tiny function is query object (an instance). You have no clue which models are being selected or in fact what is the real payload of the query. All you know that you want to modify that query to not have any filters at all.

Suggestions/Solutions?

Comment: Just a thought, why not instead construct the query without the `filter` first, then do your `qr` and `qr2`?

Comment: Because it happens 3 modules and 4k lines away. I have no control and for legal reason I cannot alter this code.

Comment: What if the query is `s.query(models.User).join(s.query(models.Page).filter(filter_x).subquery()).filter(filter_y)`? Should both filters be removed?

Comment: Well whatever I get I will be happy. Right now I am browsing source code and trying random things. So for example another solution might be to get access to original entity that is put into s.query()